# Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding in wcf

Tags: wcf

i have develop simple duplex service. my service project has one svc file called **ChatHandler.svc**

when i am right click on svc file and choose view in browser then i am getting error called
**Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding**

i am not being able to fix it. here i am giving my web.config endpoint details

```
<services>
  <service name="ChatService.ChatHandler" behaviorConfiguration="behaviorConfig">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:1648/ChatService/ChatHandler.svc" />
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1647/ChatService/ChatHandler.svc" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="tcp"
                      binding="netTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
                      contract="ChatService.IChat"/>

    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:1645/ChatService/mex"
                      binding="mexTcpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

tell me what is wrong in my endpoint. what i need to change as a result i can browse my svc file in browser. thanks

Comment: The easiest would be to remove line with tcp base address and just write the whole address directly in the `endpoint` node (as `address` attribute). However, please remember that You probably won't be able to host netTcp binding with Visual Studio Development Server. You should rather host that service in IIS or as a self-hosted service.